# Download data from FTP Website

Tags: ftp, wget

There is something which I am missing or might be the whole case. So I am trying to download NCDC data from [NCDC Datasets](ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/noaa/) and unable to do it the unix box.

The command which I have used this far are

```
wget ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov:21/pub/data/noaa/1901/029070-99999-1901.gz">029070-99999-1901.gz
```

This is for one file, but will be very happy if I can downlaod the entire parent directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have a lonely " just before the >

to download everything you can try this command to get the whole directory content

```
wget -r ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov:21/pub/data/noaa/1901/*
```

Comment: it worked like charm. Is it possible to provide the path where it should send the downloaded file. Also while downloading the 1902 file it worked but didn't download the data

Comment: Running your command where you want it to get downloaded or specify it using mycommand > mylocationfolder

Comment: Sorry mate for trouble. If I want to wget only certain files like 1901-1903 , how shall I go for this ... I am using "wget -r ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/noaa/{1901-2013}/*" but it doesnt seems to work

Comment: got it... for future reference to anyone... wget -r ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/noaa{1901..2013}/*

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in {1990..1993} 
do
    echo "$i"
    cd /home/chile/data
    # -nH Disable generation of host-prefixed directories
    # -nd all files will get saved to the current directory
    # -np Do not ever ascend to the parent directory when retrieving recursively. 
    # -R index.html*,227070*.gz* don't download files with this regex

wget -r -nH -nd -np -R *.html,999999-99999-$i.gz* http://www1.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/noaa/$i/
    /data/noaa/$i/

done
```